# Correct keyboard shortcut for a web application

Tags: javascript, web-applications, interface, keyboard-shortcuts, usability

I am documenting the keyboard shortcuts for our web application. Please share if these are not the right keys to use, for any reason, such as interference with browser's own keyboard shortcuts/ OS shortcuts or general usability's sake.

The shortcut initiator will be     <kbd>SPACE</kbd>    , similar to how some Gmail shortcuts use '*' as initiator. The list of shortcuts is rather big, but here are a few of the key ones:

**Functionality - shortcut**

- SAVE -     <kbd>SPACE</kbd>    +<kbd>S</kbd>
- Undo -     <kbd>SPACE</kbd>    +<kbd>Z</kbd>
- Redo -     <kbd>SPACE</kbd>    +<kbd>Y</kbd>

Our web application is a one page, without scroll, JavaScript  application. We are considering John Resig's [Hotkeys](https://github.com/jeresig/jquery.hotkeys), [Mousetrap](http://craig.is/killing/mice), and [jKey](http://oscargodson.github.com/jKey/) for the plugin. Any thoughts, warnings would be much appreciated on the use of the above keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: Is there a reason not to use Ctrl-S, Ctrl-Z and Ctrl-Y? Of those, I would think only Ctrl-S seriously interferes with the browser's shortcuts, but given that it is a web **application**, is the browser's own Save functionality really needed?

Comment: @PPvG - Ctrl-S will bring up the browser save page. From what I have read, while Firefox will not interfere with ctrl-S, others are not so lenient.

Answer (score 0):

[Hotkeys](http://jaywcjlove.github.io/hotkeys/) is a robust JavaScript library for capturing keyboard input and key combinations entered. It has no dependencies.

```
hotkeys('escape+a,escape+b,escape+z', function(event,handler){
    switch(handler.key){
        case "escape+s":alert('you pressed escape+s!');break;
        case "escape+z":alert('you pressed escape+z!');break;
        case "escape+y":alert('you pressed escape+y!');break;
    }
});
```

Hotkeys understands the modifiers `⇧`, `shift`, `option`, `⌥`, `alt`, `ctrl`, `control`, `command`, and `⌘`.

The following special keys can be used for shortcuts: `backspace`, `tab`, `clear`, `enter`, `return`, `esc`, `escape`, `space`, `up`, `down`, `left`, `right`, `home`, `end`, `pageup`, `pagedown`, `del`, `delete` and `f1` through `f19`.